# Implement aurelia + breeze + validation?

Tags: breeze, aurelia, aurelia-breeze

Have any of you implemented aurelia + breeze + validation?
Is there an example available?
When I implement only the breeze it validates, but does not show errors (in release 1.0.0 show errors but dont in last realase (2.2.0) the feature was removed) in the form?

### Attempts made:

[Using Aurelia-Validation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/) (My attempt shown below)

---

[Breeze-Validation](https://www.danyow.net/form-validation-with-breeze-and-aurelia/) (This, only works on version 1.0.0 (or lower) of the aurelia breeze feature has been removed)

---

**Attempt**

My main.js:

```
Import 'bootstrap';
Import BreezeValidator from './breeze-validator';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  aurelia.use
    .plugin('aurelia-breeze');
  aurelia.use
    .plugin('aurelia-validation', config => config.customValidator(BreezeValidator));

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

Error message: Unhandled rejection Error: key / value can not be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject / register something that does not exist with DI

Comment: May not fix your issue, but you don't need multiple `aurelia.use`'s. `aurelia.use.standardConfiguration().developmentLogging().plugin('aurelia-breeze').etc...`

Comment: I know this, I only use this way to separate by subject, thank you

Comment: You say that it works but it doesn't show errors in the form... Have you configured a customRenderer?

Comment: I was able to do show errors but only in version 1.0.0 in the following none presented error messages.
Now I have two challenges to make Breeze work in version 2.2.0 and integrate it with the aurelia-validation plugin